# Escuchar cambios en NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy trabajando con NodeJS (Express) e instale Nodemon para que escuche los cambios y reinicie el servidor, todo bien.
Hasta que comence a trabajar con HBS (Template Engine) y nodemon no escucha los cambios en estos archivos .hbs solamente escucha mi server.js y helper.js

¿Alguna idea de por que ocurre?

```
// Requires

const express = require('express');
// Load Express
const app = express();
const hbs = require('hbs');


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


// Import Helpers


// Middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



// Express HBS Engine
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');



// Routes

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})




// Config Port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Running in port: ${port}`);
})
```

Es mi server.js si de algo sirve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que te falta configurar las opciones de `nodemon` para que vigile los cambios en los archivos `.hbs` ya que por defecto (si no alteramos las opciones) siempre vigilará archivos `.js`, `.mjs`, `.coffee`, `.litcoffee` y `.json`.

Para lograr que vigile los cambios en los archivos que requieres tienes algunas opciones:

**Usar un archivo `nodemon.json`**

Como indica la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#config-files), puedes crear un archivo llamado `nodemon.json` en el directorio o carpeta raíz de tu proyecto. En dicho archivo puedes colocar los siguiente:

```
{
  "ext": "js,json,hbs"
}
```

Con esto le estás indicando a `nodemon` que vigile los cambios en todos los archivos con extensión `js`, `json` y `hbs`.

**Usar el archivo `package.json`**

Como indica la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#packagejson), puedes poner toda la configuración de opciones de `nodemon` en un solo lugar: el archivo `package.json`. Simplemente debes añadir lo siguiente a tu archivo `package.json`:

```
// ...
"nodemonConfig": {
    "ext": "js,json,hbs"
}
```

**Especificar la lista de archivos a vigilar como parte del comando de ejecución**

Nuevamente según la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list), puedes especificar la extensión a vigilar usando la opción `-e` seguida de la lista de extensiones (sin poner el punto) separadas por coma.

Si ejecutas desde la consola el comando para iniciar tu aplicación, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
>nodemon -e js,json,hbs index.js
```

Con esto le estás indicando a `nodemon` que vigile los archivos con la extensión que le pasas en la lista.

Si el comando lo tienes dentro de un valor `script` en tu archivo `package.json` simplemente agrega la opción de extensión. Por ejemplo, si corres tu aplicación con `npm run dev`, entonces tu valor para el script `dev` debe lucir así:

```
// ...
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon -e js,json,hbs index.js" // <- aqui agregas las opciones de extensión
},
// ...
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Exactamente eso era, funciona de maravilla!